# Connecting to an external database from an app deployed in Kubernetes

Tags: spring-boot, kubernetes, environment-variables, minikube

I'm deploying a Spring Boot app in minikube that connects to a database running on the host.  Following the 12 factor app recommendations I use environment variables for the necessary configuration:

```
SPRING_DATASOURCE_DRIVER_CLASS_NAME=org.postgresql.Driver
SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=...
SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://<HOST_IP_FROM_K8S>:5432/myservice
SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=...
```

The kubernetes docs only show how to set environment variables in the service and deployment .yaml files which I don't want to do.  Is there a way to pass environment variables on the command line for minikube or kubectl when I create the deployment?  (In Docker I do this with -e.)

Note that the environment variables have to be set before starting the app or it crashes.

Comment: It's better to use configMaps to inject variables to the Pod. We can pass env variables to using kubectl , but may I know how you are trying to start the application ? is that as a Pod or you are expecting a combination of Yaml and your env variables?

Comment: I start it with `kubectl create -f deployment.yaml`.  I would expect to set the env vars on that command line because they have to be available to the app when it starts.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following Ansil's comment above I used `configmap` and `secret` to pass the configuration like this:

```
kubectl create secret generic springdatasourcepassword --from-literal=SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD=postgres
kubectl create secret generic springdatasourceusername --from-literal=SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME=postgres
kubectl create configmap springdatasourcedriverclassname --from-literal=SPRING_DATASOURCE_DRIVER_CLASS_NAME=org.postgresql.Driver
kubectl create configmap springdatasourceurl --from-literal=SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL=jdbc:postgresql://172.18.0.1:5432/bookservice
```

These are referenced in the deployment.yaml file like this:

```
env:
- name: GET_HOSTS_FROM
  value: dns
- name: SPRING_DATASOURCE_DRIVER_CLASS_NAME
  valueFrom:
    configMapKeyRef:
      name: springdatasourcedriverclassname
      key: SPRING_DATASOURCE_DRIVER_CLASS_NAME
- name: SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL
  valueFrom:
    configMapKeyRef:
      name: springdatasourceurl
      key: SPRING_DATASOURCE_URL
- name: SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD
  valueFrom:
    secretKeyRef:
      name: springdatasourcepassword
      key: SPRING_DATASOURCE_PASSWORD
- name: SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME
  valueFrom:
    secretKeyRef:
      name: springdatasourceusername
      key: SPRING_DATASOURCE_USERNAME
```

A full explanation can be found [here](https://medium.com/google-cloud/kubernetes-configmaps-and-secrets-68d061f7ab5b).

Comment: if i m running a spring boot app on local env , is it possible to use all the kubectl secrets ?  since yes, where should be referenced the secret.yml and deployment.yml file ?    the env vars created on those 2 files are not visible  in my case

Answer (score 0):

We have no direct option with `create` subcommand in `kubectl` to pass the environmental variables.

You may use [**Helm**](https://helm.sh/) to customize deployment.

(Example: https://docs.bitnami.com/kubernetes/how-to/deploy-java-application-kubernetes-helm/)

Comment: That passes credentials in the .yaml file which you aren't supposed to do.